# How to use getElementById in php while loop

Tags: php, javascript

I need the JavaScript to only display the selected value next to each radio. I've got two radios in one line next to each user and I want to display what value was selected for each particular user. The problem is that when I'm selecting a value, that value is displaying next to all users.

#### Javascript:

```
function displayResult(szybkosc){
    var n=value=szybkosc;
    var u=n.split("|")[1]; 
    document.getElementById('result1').innerText = ' '+u;
    document.getElementById('result2').innerText = ' '+u;
}
```

#### PHP:

```
$i = 1;
while($i < 3){
    $result = "result" . $i;
    echo "user number ".$i."
    input type='radio' name='szybkosc' onclick='displayResult(this.value)' value='$sp1[id]|1|$row[id]' />
    input type='radio' name='szybkosc' onclick='displayResult(this.value)' value='$sp1[id]|3|$row[id]' />span id='$result'>span>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Even if the creators of both **php** & **Javascript** come together I don't think they would be able to solve your problem from what you have just explained.

Comment: _PHP_ and _JavaScript_ are executed at different times; _PHP_ first on the server to generate the page source (possibly even generating _JavaScript_) then _JavaScript_ as defined in the source on the client's machine.

Comment: Is this code from an email?

Comment: no i just was trying to write clear so you saying that it's not possible to display value in php loop case ?

Comment: You have an unatched quote in `var u = n.split(|")[1];`. Is that just a typo in the question, or in the original code?

Comment: You can't have two different functions with the same name `displayResult`.

Comment: Why do you assign a variable `value`, but don't use it?

Comment: You're missing the beginning `<` before your `input` tags.

Answer (score 1):

You have some serious issues going on with your code. You need to study the basics, ALOT. Here's some improvements to help you get on the right track.

[Live demo (click)](http://jsbin.com/epIkUH/1/edit)

```
<input type="radio" class="foo" value="one"> <!-- don't use "onclick" in your html! html can't "do" things. Javascript is going to make this work, so add clicks in javascript! -->
<p class="result"></p>
<input type="radio" class="foo" value="two">
<p class="result"></p>

var radios = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
var results = document.getElementsByClassName('result');

for (var i=0; i < radios.length; ++i) {
  addClick(radios[i], i);
}

function addClick(radio, i) {
  radio.addEventListener('click', function() { //add the click function here in js
    results[i].innerText = this.value;
  });
}
```

Comment: but it has to be a php while loop

Comment: @user2759825  Right... create the html I showed you with php. My html is very simple to produce.

Comment: @user2759825 but really....I can't even begin to understand what you were trying to do with that php code. You just need a simple loop. SO isn't for getting people to do your job for you (which I mostly just did anyway). You can figure out a loop for yourself. It's one of the most basic concepts.

Comment: I created just an example to make easier, I need while loop because I m selecting data from database and as long as something is match to my query, loop will be returning result which is user name and each of user will be rating  that's why is two values for one user 1 or 3 so it's slide different then ur example

Comment: @user2759825 My example demonstrates the technique to do everything you need to do. Now you just need to use those techniques to achieve your specific goal and use your loop to generate the actual html you need. I'm not going to write your code for you so that you can copy and paste it.